# Aligning Items in Nav Bar Horizontally with graphic

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a RoR site with twitter bootstrap.  I am adjusting my navigation bar.  It is supposed to have an image(logo) in the center with list items to the left and right of it.  I have the logo in the center and I have two list items, one on the left of the logo and one on the right. Unfortunately the two list items are not aligned with my graphic in the center.  I am guessing it is something within my selectors and all of my list items are following the same rule. I think I have to set different rules for my list items that are text/links and different rules for my logo. Here is my css and html:

html:

```
<section id="nav_holder" class="nav_default">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li class="prelogo"><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li id="logo" class="logo1"><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
@import 'bootstrap';

.nav_default {
    background-color: #ff3600;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

nav {
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    width: 980px;
    left: 45%;
    margin-left: -490px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.navigation {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}

.navigation li {
    list-style: none;
    height: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-family: "futura-pt",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.prelogo {
padding-right: 96px;
}

.logo1 {
padding-left: 525px;
background: url('ctclogonewnobg.png') no-repeat left 1px;
}

.logo {

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50em;

}

.masthead {
    background: url('CDRedBG.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
body {
    padding-top: 40px;
    background: url('escheresque_@2X.png');
}

.container-center{
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

@import 'bootstrap-responsive';
```

How can I get my logo to be centered while having my other list items aligned horizontally? Right now they are both above and even overlapping part of my center logo.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, have you tried using the "float" variable for both .logo and .logo1 ?

e.g.

```
float:left
```

Secondly, try adding

```
position:relative
```

to .logo and .logo1 as this may help in conjunction with the float variable.

Thirdly, the margin entries under .logo can be shortened with

```
margin:0 auto;
```

which will center the content.

Comment: Thanks, Im going to try these out and see which works best. I actually got it to work by using "line-height". I'm not sure which option is "best" but I will play around with them! :)